# Digit Folding Algorithm for Hash Table

Tags: c, data-structures, hashtable

i'm studying with book that about data structure.
i'm reading hash table chapter, in Digits Folding section, it shows hash algorithm.

```
int Hash(char* key, int keyLength, int tableSize)
{
     int i = 0;
     int hashValue= 0;

     for(i=0; i<keyLenth; i++)
        hashValue += key[i];

     return hashValue % tableSize;
}
```

Replace each element of the string with ASCII code(0-127) and add these values ​​separately.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJ0Ck.jpg)

But there is one problem. If the size of the hash table is 12289 and the maximum length of the string is 10 digits, the hash function returns 10X127 = 1270, it returns only the address between 0 and 1270, so the address between 1271 and 12288 is not used at all.

The size of the hash table, 12289, is 11000000000001 in binary. This is a total of 14 bits. On the other hand, the maximum address value of 1270 is 10011110110, so only 11 bits are used. This fact shows that the three bits are never used. So every time the loop of the Hash function is iterated, we move the hashValue 3 bits to the left and add the next ASCII code. This will theoretically be able to hash all addresses.

My question is why should I shift 3 bits to the left? Is there any reason I should not move it to the right?

Comment: @Bob__ sorry, update!

Comment: @Ruks sorry, update!

Comment: "*My question is why should I shift 3 bits to the left? Is there any reason I should not move it to the right?*" - It depends on your [endianess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. I'm not sure if you copied your code or just scribbled it, but currently your code is not a hash code but just a transfer function of the last ascii code. I'm guessing you meant to XOR the values?
2. It's not quite clear what your suggested function is, so you should clarify, however, if you just XOR on text based data, you're not doing a very good hash function. Suppose your data turns out to be only even digits? And there are other degenerations in ASCII.
   I'm assuming hashValue ^= key [i]
3. You shouldn't shift to the right (or left for that matter), because you lose bits. Suppose you XOR at the 7 right bits of hashValue and shift to the right. Your hash value only holds only the 4 right bits of the value you just added! It would take a bit longer if you shift to the left but the same holds. You're dropping bits at one end of your hash value. You should check for a good hash function.
   Wikipedia is your friend (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)
4. Addition is slightly better as far as degenerate value but it still creates a non uniform hash (the middle would under most data be more populated than the ends).